# Saving results to a destination table on BigQuery is not available for some queries and it is for other. Anyone know why and how to fix it?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to run a query and add its results to an existing destination table, but it doesn't give me the option to do it under the query settings.

I can only run it and save the results once it has runned. However, I need to schedule this query to feed that table daily but the destination table option is not available in that case either.

I know the query I'm trying to schedule is a bit more complicated than other I've done. It's longer and using the WITH clause.

Any ideas what other alternatives I have and why this is happening?[image]

Comment: can you give us a query to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I found how to make it allow me to use the destination table option. At the beginning of my query I was using this and taking it off made it work:

DECLARE time_limit INT64;
SET time_limit = 300;

In case I was asked to change the time_limit we are using for our purposes. I was trying to avoid having to change the time limit on every single part of my query.

Is this how it's supposed to be? that the destination table is not an option when declaring a variable? Am I doing something wrong? (Still relatively new to sql and BigQuery so I know that's totally possible lol)